# Is there a standard python3 method to do a "stepped" lookup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to avoid long if-elifs such as:

```
 output = some_value_a
 if age > timedelta(days=400):
     output = some_value_b
 elif age > timedelta(days=300):
     output = some_value_c
 elif age > timedelta(days=200):
     output = some_value_d
 elif age > timedelta(days=150):
     output = some_value_e
 ...
```

I want to put all my comparison timedeltas and my output values into a dictionary (that is not the problem) or into two lists and call a function.
So it's a bit like numpy's interp(), but discrete.

It should be called like:

```
my_func(test_value, list_of_steps, list_of_outputs)
```

or

```
my_func(test_value, dict_of_steps_as_keys_and_outputs_as_outputs)
```

I know I can write that method myself but usually there already is one and I just don't know the module and the name of it.

Comment: `next(v for p, v in [(timedelta(...), 69), (timedelta(...), 42), ...] if age > p)`…?

Comment: [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Comment: I like deceze's thinking. I have adapted it for a dict, like so:
next(v for p, v in age_sales.items() if p <= timedelta(days=...)). The dictionary makes sure that there is also a value the lowest possible number of days. Can I accept this answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html), e.g.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from bisect import bisect_left

def get_val(time_delta, time_steps, outputs):
    """time_steps is list of time steps in ascending order;
    outputs is list of corresponding outputs"""
    index = bisect_left(time_steps, time_delta)
    if index > 0:
        return outputs[index-1]
    else:
        # time_delta is less than the smallest time step in time_steps list
        return None

# test code
time_steps = [timedelta(days=delta) for delta in (150, 200, 300, 400)]
values = [f'value {delta}' for delta in (150, 200, 300, 400)]

for days in (100, 150, 180, 250, 410):
    print(days, get_val(timedelta(days=days), time_steps, values))
```